# Image masking fails on iOS10 beta3

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, ios10

For some time now we use the following code to mask a grayscale image without transparency to a coloured image.

This always worked fine until Apple released iOS 10 beta 3. Suddenly the mask is not applied anymore resulting in just a square box being returned with te given color.

The logic behind this can be found at
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html

under the header *Masking an Image with an Image Mask*

The logic of this code:
* Take an grayscale image without alpha
* Create an solid image with the given color
* Create a mask from the given image
* Mask the solid image with the created mask
* Output is a masked image with also respect for colors in between (gray might be light red i.e.).

Has anyone an idea how to fix this function?
If you have XCode 8 beta 3 you can run this code and on a simulator lower than iOS 10 this will work correct and on iOS 10 it will just create a square box

Example image:
[image: Example image]

```
    public static func image(maskedWith color: UIColor, imageNamed imageName: String) -> UIImage? {

    guard let image = UIImage(named: imageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) else {
        return nil
    }

    guard image.size != CGSize.zero else {
        return nil
    }

    guard
        let maskRef = image.cgImage,
        let colorImage = self.image(with: color, size: image.size),
        let cgColorImage = colorImage.cgImage,
        let dataProvider = maskRef.dataProvider
        else {
        return nil
    }

    guard
        let mask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskRef.width, height: maskRef.height, bitsPerComponent: maskRef.bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel: maskRef.bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow: maskRef.bytesPerRow, provider: dataProvider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true),
        let masked = cgColorImage.masking(mask)
        else {
        return nil
    }

    let result = UIImage(cgImage: masked, scale: UIScreen.main().scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

    return result
}

public static func image(with color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {

    guard size != CGSize.zero else {
        return nil
    }

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main().scale)

    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }

    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context.fill(rect)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Any progress on this? I have a similar issue when stacking multiple CALayers and using masks. Did you file with Apple?

Comment: Yes we did report it to Apple already. We hope that they will solve it in the next beta or else start exploring different options (or hoping that someone has a nice solution)

Comment: I've not yet made any progress on my issue. A sample project to repro the problem doesn't have the problem :-(. Its like the CALayer is quantizing the image data to fewer bits as it contains more child layers.

Comment: The problem I was having got fixed with iOS10 beta4 :-). Hope yours is fixed too.

Comment: Yup received yesterday an email from Apple if i could verify that my bug report was still valid with the new beta. Tested it this morning and the problem was 'gone'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in iOS10 beta 4.